# Create a glossary alphabet in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a glossary with the letters of the alphabet in a list, and the content in another list. Clicking on each letter will display the content of that letter like this:

```
<ul class="alphabet">
    <li class="selected"><a class="alpha alpha-a">A</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-b">B</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-c">C</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-d">D</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-e">E</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-f">F</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-g">G</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-h">H</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-i">I</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-j">J</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-k">K</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-l">L</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-m">M</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-n">N</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-o">O</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-p">P</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-q">Q</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-r">R</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-s">S</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-t">T</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-u">U</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-v">V</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-w">W</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-x">X</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-y">Y</a></li>
    <li><a class="alpha alpha-z">Z</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-objects list-object-a selected">
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-objects list-object-b">
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
etc.
```

```
<script>
    $(".alphabet .alpha-a").click(function() {
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected").siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
        $("ul.list-object-a").addClass("selected").siblings("ul.list-objects").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".alphabet .alpha-b").click(function() {
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected").siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
        $("ul.list-object-b").addClass("selected").siblings("ul.list-objects").removeClass("selected");
    });
    etc.
</script>
```

I would like to simplify the javascript so I won't have to repeat the snippet for each letter. Any ideas? @Muhammad Umer ? Thanks :)

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com it's the same, `.alphabet` is the parent `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.When click on anchor tag add and remove `slected Class` from the parent.Then garb the text of the anchor tag and append to the `<ul>` tag class where respective anchor tag contents present.I mean to say if you click on 'B' it should select `.list-object-b` not `.list-object-a`.the code `$("ul.list-object-" + $(this).text().toLowerCase())` does the same

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[class^="alpha alpha-"]').click(function () {
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected").siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
        $("ul.list-object-" + $(this).text().toLowerCase()).addClass("selected").siblings("ul.list-objects").removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: @WimMertens Glad the solution works for you ,  If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

Using `href` as reference to the list you want to show.

For example, clicking `<a class="alpha" href="#object-a">A</a>` 
will display the list having an `id="object-a"`

Check the following codes and try to run it.

```js
$(".alphabet li").click(function() {
  $($(this).find('a').data('href')).addClass('selected').siblings('.list-objects.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.alphabet li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.alphabet .selected {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.list-objects {
  display: none;
}
.list-objects.selected {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="alphabet">
  <li class="selected">
    <a class="alpha" data-href="#object-a">A</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="alpha" data-href="#object-b">B</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="object-a" class="list-objects selected">
  <li>
    <a href="">Item A1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item A2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item A3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="object-b" class="list-objects">
  <li>
    <a href="">Item B1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item B2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item B3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No prob. @WimMertens

Comment: I tried this, but on click the page jumps back to that ID which is not ideal. Any way we can do it without adding the href?

Comment: @WimMertens , i edited this one. i used `data-href` instead. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards:

```
$(class^=".alpha .alpha-").click(function() {
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected").siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
    $("ul.list-object-a").addClass("selected").siblings("ul.list-objects").removeClass("selected");
});
```